# Is there anyway to use tensorflow-gpu with intel(r) hd graphics 520?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am working on my master's project which uses keras and tensorflow backend .I have intel(r) hd graphics 520 ,So I am not able to use tensorflow-gpu. The cpu version is working fine .Is there any way to use tensorflow-gpu with the intel(r) hd graphics 520?

Comment: So you have onboard graphics and not a dedicated GPU?  And from what I know, Tensorflow GPU support requires nvidia's Cuda and CudNN packages which are only supported by nvidia graphics cards.

Comment: Maybe you can find this useful. [OpenMined](https://openmined.org/) is a community focused on building open-source technology for the decentralized ownership of data and intelligence. The ML/DL library is being built in Unity and it cross-compile over almost every GPU on the planet.

Comment: @Alber8295 is it free service?

Comment: Of course! It's an open source project @HrishikeshKulkarni

Answer (score 18):

Tensorflow GPU support needs `Nvidia Cuda` and `CuDNN` packages installed. For `GPU` accelerated training you will need a dedicated `GPU`. `Intel` onboard graphics can't be used for that purpose.

You can see full requirements for `tensorflow-gpu` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements)

Comment: When I see the details in my Task Manager, 2 GPUs are being shown there. GPU 0 - Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 with shared memory of 4GB and GPU 1 - Radeon(TM) 540 Graphics with 4GB shared memory and 2 GB dedicated memory. Are these GPUs any useful for tensorflow?

Comment: Not sure about using AMD GPUs for TF. I think not possible

Comment: So can I shift all my code execution to my CPU? It's is a very basic LSTM RNN code. Will I be able to run that on my i5 8th gen processor?

Answer (score 1):

I saw [this page](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2020/09/08/open-sourcing-tensorflow-with-directml/) just now (published on Sep 2020). Accordingly, it is possible to run Tensorflow on DirectX 12 compatible GPUs using [DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML) library. It is called **[TensorFlow-DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml)**.

> TensorFlow is an end-to-end open source platform for machine learning. This repository is a fork of tensorflow that leverages DirectML to provide cross-vendor hardware acceleration on Windows 10 and the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). TensorFlow with DirectML enables training and inference of complex machine learning models on a wide range of DirectX 12-compatible hardware.

There are some other discussion about OpenCL [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17578/using-tensorflow-with-intel-gpu).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anaconda you can do the following:

1. Create new Environment and name it TF-GPU for example and select python version 3.7.
2. Open Anaconda CMD and write this command: pip install tensorflow-directml.
   It is working fine for my AMD Radeon and Intel Iris GPUs