# GPU needed for installing tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, hardware, tensor

I am thinking of installing tensorflow gpu for ubuntu but I am a bit lost on the nvidia aspect.

My laptop's graphics card is Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)  which I understand is not nvidia. Does this mean that I cannot download a nvidia driver? If I can still proceed, how do I select the driver needed from this website: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us ?

I am sorry if I don't know much about hardware!

Comment: If you want to install tensorflow GPU you can't do that with Intel onboard graphics. See here for more : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399802/is-there-anyway-to-use-tensorflow-gpu-with-intelr-hd-graphics-520/47400454#47400454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and install tensorflow GPU but it won't work with GPU acceleration. Intel GPUs are not supported by TensorFlow (or any DL framework), mostly only NVIDIA GPUs are supported.

You can always use TensorFlow only in the CPU with the non-GPU tensorflow package.