# Getting modulenotfound error when importing tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, modulenotfounderror

I am following neural nine's tutorial on how to build a chatbot (witch can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg&ab_channel=NeuralNine)) and i had some issues installing tensorflow, but i finally did it, by first installing `tensorflow-gpu`, and then installing tensorflow.

When i ran the program with these tensorflow imports:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Documents/Python Projects/chatbot/traning.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow.keras
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from absl import logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'
```

I tried reinstalling abseil, but that didn't work. Then i checked online and most of the answers are suggesting that the person has installed abseil on python 2.x and that they just have to use `pip3`. I do not have python 2, so that is not possible. The question that is similar can be found [here](https://www.xspdf.com/help/50889706.html)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add the code you've used? Have you checked GPU compatibility here: ( https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu )? Have you tried simply `pip install absl`?

Comment: It looks like you need to have a Nvidia GPU. Is that correct? (I have an Intel HD Graphics 4000). Also i have tried `pip install absl`, but it said the library did not exist. It turns out that the command is `pip install absl-py`. But i already had the package, so i reinstalled it. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Intel's Graphics Cards are not officially supported by `tensorflow-gpu` (Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47400454/11048201)).

I found, however, a project pointed out [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17705/72021) suggesting this [OpenCL Solution](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl) where it is allegedly possible to use an Intel GPU ([issue where compatibility is refereed](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl/issues/82))